# Custom select input Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I currently building a custom dropdown component in Angular 4.x, this is its template:

```
<div class="vet-input-container vet-input-container--select" [ngClass]="inputClass()" [ngSwitch]="type">
  <div class="vet-input-area" (click)="toggleOpen($event)">
    <button tabindex="-1" type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="vet-input-label vet-btn vet-btn--fit" *ngIf="labeled">
      <i [ngClass]="labelIconClass"></i>
    </button>
    <input type="text" class="vet-input">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down vet-input-dropdown-icon"></i>    
  </div>
  <div class="vet-input-options">
    <div class="option" *ngFor="let item of collection">
      {{displayFn(item)}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vet-input-errors">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue is when i open the "options div", this element is overlaped by others elements sibling than mi custom component. I know about the z-index, but put this on my component, force me to check other sibling elements everytime, and this makes a not reusable component.

I inspected semantic.css and bootstrap dropdown components and these have a z-index style defined in elements within the component and this makes me feel confused.

On the other hand, check angular 2 material select and this is put in a overlay elements, in this way it makes sense that the custom select overlay all elements.

Please, need an explication about how the drowdowns of semantic.css and bootstrap overlay all sibling elements, no matter the level.

UPDATE: I tried replacing my template with semantic-ui and ng-primefaces dropdowns component, but both are overlaped by sibling components.

This the layout that contains my custom inputs and selects components. Sibling input is overlaying the select options.

```
<div class="flex flex-col-layout ai-stretch">
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="Nombre de su veterinaria" formControlName="branchName">
      </app-dnj-input>
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="Nombres" formControlName="veterinarianName">
      </app-dnj-input>
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="Apellidos" formControlName="veterinarianLastName">
      </app-dnj-input>
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="Correo electrónico" formControlName="veterinarianEmail">
      </app-dnj-input>
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="Repita su correo" formControlName="veterinarianConfirmEmail">
      </app-dnj-input>
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="Contraseña" formControlName="veterinarianPassword">
      </app-dnj-input>
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="Repita su contraseña" formControlName="veterinarianConfirmPassword">
      </app-dnj-input>
      <app-dnj-select placeholder="rol" formControlName="veterinarianRole"[collection]="roleList"
      [displayFn]="displayRoleFn">
      </app-dnj-select>
      <app-dnj-input placeholder="rol" formControlName="veterinarianRole" type="select" [collection]="roleList"
      [displayFn]="displayRoleFn">
      </app-dnj-input>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the `vet-input-container` position: relative and then the menu options should be given position: absolute and z-index: 100 (the amount doesn't really matter, as long as its higher than the rest of your content).